# Adobe flex "could not resolve <s:HBox> to a component implementation" error

Tags: flash, apache-flex, datagrid, flash-builder

I want to load a datagrid to display the query results by web service.

But I get the "could not resolve  to a component implementation" error and cannot proceed.

My code is as follows:

```
<s:HBox height="95%" width="95%" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
            <s:DataGrid id="datagrid" width="645" height="100%"    selectionChange="selectionChangeHandler(event)">
                <s:columns>
                    <s:DataGridColumn headerText="User Name" dataField="userName"/>
                    <s:DataGridColumn headerText="User Email" dataField="userEmail"/>
                    <s:DataGridColumn headerText="Contact No" dataField="contactNo"/>
                </s:columns>
            </s:DataGrid>
        </s:HBox>
```

If I change spark to mx, then I get another error:

Could not resolve attribute 'selectionChange' for component type mx.controls.Datagrid

What is the corresponding attribute of 'selectionChange' in mx?

How can I solve the problem? I am using Adobe flash builder 4.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use HGroup instead of HBox, this component doesn't exists in spark package.
Try this:

```
<s:HGroup height="95%" width="95%" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
   <s:DataGrid id="datagrid" width="645" height="100%"    selectionChange="selectionChangeHandler(event)">
       <s:columns>
           <s:ArrayList>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name"/>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="phone" headerText="Phone"/>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="email" headerText="Email"/>
            </s:ArrayList>
       </s:columns>
    </s:DataGrid>
</s:HGroup>
```

Comment: Hi Astyan, thanks for the reply, but after I changed to HGroup, I got "Could not resolve <s:DataGridColumn> to a component implementation" error.

Answer (score 1):

@Astyan

```
<s:HGroup height="95%" width="95%" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
   <s:DataGrid id="datagrid" width="645" height="100%"  selectionChange="selectionChangeHandler(event)">
       <s:columns>
           <s:ArrayList>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name"/>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="phone" headerText="Phone"/>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="email" headerText="Email"/>
            </s:ArrayList>
      </s:columns>
    </s:DataGrid>
</s:HGroup>
```

I found an error in the posted code. The close tag for  was not present.  Once I put in the closing tage it worked.  The other thing to make sure is that you do not have excessive white space in your tags.  The compiler can get very picky when there is extra white space.  Let me know if this helps.